# Asp.net mvc server side timer

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am creating an online quiz application and need server side timer. For example if the user opens another browser or refresh the page or leave and back time shoud be proper.

Now i am using jquery timer and in every 5 minutes send ajax request  to store proper information into the database. Also when the user answers the question i immediately send  again  ajax requst  for the same purpose.

Should i use signalr instead? What would be more proper way to handle server side timer in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a session, you could simply store the timestamp of when the user began taking the quiz in session state.

You could tell the time of any future event by looking at the timestamp of that event, minus the timestamp of when the user took the survey.

Example (server-side code):

```
if (Session["startTime"] == null)
{
    Session["startTime"] = DateTime.Now;
}

var ticksRemaining = DateTime.Now - Session["startTime"];
// Use ticksRemaining to populate the start value for the count-down timer
// Works just fine even if they reload the page or open a new browser tab.
// You won't catch if they open a brand-new browser and start a new session,
// but that's a different kind of problem.
```

Comment: On client side there should be count down timer, and if he refresh or open it to another browser client time won't be proper

Comment: On page load, send the time remaining as part of the HTTP response. If you're using a e.g. JavaScript timer, populate the time to count down from using the variable stored in session. Added a little example code.

Comment: On the client side i should update session stardate in every second. Nice solution but another browser or if user leaves the page and then back problem still exist

Comment: I think signalr is the solution

Comment: If the user uses another browser, there is no practical solution. If he clears cookies or uses private mode browsing there is no practical solution. If he leaves the page and comes back, without clearing cookies, he'll still have the session and all will be well. If people have to log in to take the test, you can store the start date in the database also, and if Session["startTime"] is null, check for a value in the database before assigning it to current time.

Comment: How is SignalR going to detect that someone is using a different browser?

Comment: I found a nice article about it. I dont have a big experience in signalr but it is possible. But it also possible without it. I can set interval which triggers in every 5 minutes, and when  user answrer question send again ajax request. But it wont be exact time, there would be 3-4 seconds mistake

Comment: I will use user leave event and save his/her last datetime . Found it thank you  anyway